# Is there a word which means "having a frequency of decades" or "per decade"? What about century and millennium?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a document with the headings: daily, weekly, monthly, yearly, and decadely. Google Chrome, Google Docs, and Dictionary.com insist that "decadely" is not a word. Furthermore, deacadely sounds and looks weird to me.

Is there a word I am unaware of which captures this meaning?

What would you call something that happens each century or each millennium?

Comment: On the other end of the spectrum, "hourly" is fine, but "minutely" and "secondly" have an unrelated meaning.

Comment: "Decadal" would be an adjective for something that occurs every decade, but all the other words on this page are adverbs. "Decadally" might be a stretch.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would just use "per decade" and "per century", but the words you're looking for are ***[decennially](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decennially)*** (as in "the census is done decennially") and ***centennially*** (and ***millennially***). See [Wikipedia: Anniversary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary) for more words.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't think to search for "Anniversary," I was so focused on frequency. As far as "per X" goes, I wanted consistency in my headings and I don't really like the aesthetic of "Per Day," it seems really unnatural.

Answer (score 12):

[Decennially](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/decennially),[Centennially](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/centennially), and [Millennially](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/millennially) are probably the words you're looking for....